# Troubleshooting a Javascript class' click-event function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, onclicklistener, webflow

I have a JS 'shuffle' function that I am trying to execute every time a user clicks on the `shuffleBtn` class in my HTML. I am using classes over IDs because I have multiple `shuffleBtn` instances.

I'm not too familiar with JS/jQuery and can't see why my syntax is broken. Any pointers appreciated!

```
<script>

window.onload = function() {
  $('.shuffleBtn').on('click', function(){
  var refs = $(".ref");
    for(var i = 0; i < refs.length; i++){
        var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * refs.length -1) + 1;
        var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * refs.length -1) +1;
        refs.eq(target).before(refs.eq(target2));
    }
 };
 };
 
</script>
```

Comment: Can you paste the html with it?

Comment: I'm using Webflow so it's a little difficult, figuring out how to export the HTML now. Here's the live site in the meantime: https://ondraco.webflow.io/ref

Comment: nothing looks inherently wrong does the html dynamically load after the page loads?

Comment: also since you are already using jquery here is a good reference for onload events https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: We need more information to help you. What error message are you getting? What signs are you getting that there is a problem? Have you verified that your click handler is firing? How about the loop?

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody, I realized it's a problem with webflow and restricting tags on IDs. I restructured my HTML and it now works. You gave me good questions to consider for next time I run into a problem!